# Merge BitmapFont and UI skin in single Atlas?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d, bitmap-fonts

If I have a `UI` with a `.atlas` and a BitmapFont with a `.atlas` is there a simple way to combine these into one or do I have to merge them myself in a image file and manually offset all the elements in the combined `.atlas` to the correct position? It is doable manually but kinda tedious, and if there is a slight calculation error one might have to redo every position and/or size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can! Just let `TexturePacker` do the packing work for you:

1. Put the BitmapFont's **.png file** in the same folder where TexturePacker reads your images to pack. The same folder where all the other images are
2. Put the BitmapFont's **.fnt file** in the same folder where your skin's .atlas file is (usually in the assets folder inside android project)
3. Refresh the assets folder in eclipse (just in case..)
4. Now you can use the Bitmap font in the styles.json, like for example:

   `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: {
         default-font: { file: somefont.fnt }
   }`